# Loop AVMutableCompositionTrack

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-audio, avmutablecomposition, avasset

I have got two audio tracks on me that I combine with one another like this:

```
AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionAudioTrack setPreferredVolume:1.0];
AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:originalContentURL options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack1 = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionAudioTrack1 setPreferredVolume:0.01];
NSString *soundOne1  =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"jingle1" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundOne1];
AVAsset *avAsset1 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url1 options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack1 = [[avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
[compositionAudioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack1 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

As you can see, the first `AVAsset` is the base length for the second track, meaning that if I have a long second track it will be cut, which is just the way that I want.

However, I need to be able to loop the second track so that if the **first** one is too long, the second one goes on and on. I later have to save the resulting track on disc which is an important factor as well.

After a research I've made I found out there's no convenient way to actually loop a track in iOS. One of the ways out would be inserting the second track at `AVMutableComposition` multiple times over and over but that sounds quite strange to me. Any ideas based on the topic would be really useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it should work:

```
CMTime videoDuration = avAsset.duration;
if(CMTimeCompare(videoDuration, audioAsset.duration) == -1){
    [compositionAudioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack1 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
}else if(CMTimeCompare(videoDuration, audioAsset.duration) == 1){
     CMTime currentTime = kCMTimeZero;
     while(YES){
           CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
           CMTime totalDuration = CMTimeAdd(currentTime,audioDuration);
           if(CMTimeCompare(totalDuration, videoDuration)==1){
              audioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(totalDuration,videoDuration);

           }
           [compositionAudioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioDuration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack1 atTime:currentTime error:nil];
           currentTime = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, audioDuration);
           if(CMTimeCompare(currentTime, videoDuration) == 1 || CMTimeCompare(currentTime, videoDuration) == 0){
               break;
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm, great!

Comment: @GauravSingh I tried the code above. But get the error from `AVAssetExportSession` **The video could not be composed** error code: -11841. Any idea why it would fail? If the video duration is shorter than the mp3 it's fine.

Comment: @resting please check your code and try logging the compositionAudiotrack duration in each loop iteration to see if everything is going fine or not

Comment: This's good codes and thank author a lot. But in some situation, such as: the length of video is larger than audio duration, and the audio will loop play during video playing. I think this code: "audioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(totalDuration, timeDuringMerge);"  should be replaced by "audioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(timeDuringMerge, currentTime);"

Comment: I followed and developed same logic to repeat a video track for base duration of audio track, i.e audio track is longer than video so I need to repeat video for whole audio duration. 
My first range of video is perfectly added but next ranges/chunks of video are black. Not sure why, the logic is simple to add video track at current time and increase current time to video duration.

Answer (score 8):

On the Gaurav response you should change this line:
`audioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(totalDuration,videoDuration);`

to:
`audioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(videoDuration,currentTime);`

Otherwise the audiotrack will be longer than the video ( that will be just black )

Answer (score 2):

In swift with `repeat whiel` Loop.

> *fix video length isuue*

```
let audioLength = CMTime(value: 100, timescale: 1)
let videoLength = CMTime(value: 220, timescale: 1)

func getAudioRepeatInfo(audioLength:CMTime, videoLength:CMTime) -> [(at:CMTime, duration:CMTime)] {
    var at = [(at:CMTime, duration:CMTime)](), start = CMTime.zero
    repeat {
        let info = (at:start, duration: min(CMTimeSubtract(videoLength, start), audioLength) )
        at.append(info)
        start = CMTimeAdd(start, info.duration)
    } while start < videoLength
    return at
}

var ranges =  getAudioRepeatInfo(audioLength: audioLength, videoLength: videoLength)
```

Playground Output:

```
[(at: __C.CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0), duration: __C.CMTime(value: 100, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)),
 (at: __C.CMTime(value: 100, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0), duration: __C.CMTime(value: 100, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)),
 (at: __C.CMTime(value: 200, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0), duration: __C.CMTime(value: 20, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0))]
```

Use:

```
for info in repeatInfo {
    try compositionAudioTrack1?.insertTimeRange(.init(start: .zero, duration: info.duration), of: assetTrack, at: info.at)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gaurav answer in **Swift 5.5** (his solution is correct and working perfectly).

```
  let videoDuration = avAsset.duration

  if (CMTimeCompare(videoDuration, audioAsset.duration) == -1) {
    // Handle insertTimeRange
  } else if (CMTimeCompare(videoDuration, audioAsset.duration) == 1) {

    var currentTime = CMTime.zero

    while(true) {
      let audioDuration = audioAsset.duration
      let totalDuration = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, audioDuration)

      if (CMTimeCompare(totalDuration, videoDuration) == 1) {
        audioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(videoDuration, currentTime)
      }
  
      // Handle insertTimeRange
  
      currentTime = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, audioDuration)
      if(CMTimeCompare(currentTime, videoDuration) == 1 || CMTimeCompare(currentTime, videoDuration) == 0){
        break
      }
    }
  }
```